# __dir__ giving a circular reference but dir() is OK

Tags: python

I have the following class that tries to define a custom `__getattribute__`:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
    def __dir__(self):
        return ['x']
    def __getattribute__(self, i):
        if i not in dir(self):
            return "NOT DEFINED!"
        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(a)
```

And then I can run it fine:

```
>>> i=Item()
>>> i.x
1
>>> i.a
'NOT DEFINED!'
```

However, if I change this line:

```
if i not in dir(self):
```

To:

```
if i not in self.__dir__():
```

I get a `RecursionError` as it seems to be calling itself. Why is this so, and why does `dir()` and differently than `__dir__()`?

Comment: When you try to access `self.__dir__` you are trying to get an attribute, so `__getattribute__` will be invoked. And that tries to access `self.__dir___`... infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__getattribute__` method is called whenever the dot notation is used on an object, so `self.__dir__()` would call the `__getattribute__` method of `self` with `'__dir__'` as the argument, which, with your code, would then call `self.__dir__()` again, which calls the `__getattribute__` method again with the same argument, resulting in endless recursions.